Mongoose populate is using the wrong ID in query
I’m building a MERN app that is intended to allow users to add books to a wishlist they have on their profile.  The wishlist is an array of Book IDs.  To query the wishlist, it’s supposed to populate the associated data from the Book collection.  Instead (according to Apollo Server), it’s attempting to populate data using the profile’s ID.
Models:
const profileSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, trim: true, },
    Wishlist: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Books',
    }],
});

const bookSchema = new Schema({
    author: { type: String, trim: true, required: true},
    title: { type: String, trim: true,  required: true},
    description: { type: String, trim: true },
});

Pertinent resolvers:
wishlist: async (parent, { profileId }) => {
    return Profile.find({ _id: profileId }).populate({ path: "Wishlist"});
}

addToWishlist: async (parent, { profileId, bookId}) => {
    return Profile.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: profileId},
        {
            $addToSet: { Wishlist: {_id: bookId}},
        },
        {
            new: true,
            runValidators: true,
        }
    );
}

I have attempted rewriting the wishlist query, adding a function with exec(), and also checked and double-checked pluralization, i.e. used "Book" instead of "Books."  I also have checked with MongoDBCompass and the underlying data is in fact there.  This user's wishlist contains an ID referencing a valid book.
EDIT: The profile returned should look like this:
{
  "data": {
    "profile": {
      "email": "hello@hello.com",
      "username": "hello",
      "_id": "6624861e8b8c3a506e5fbbbc",
      "Wishlist": [
        {
          "_id": "6608da54f990723f5e23d04c"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

And the related book document is:
  "data": {
    "books": [
      {
        "_id": "6608da54f990723f5e23d04c",
        "author": "Lewis Carroll",
        "description": "Alice's Adventures in Wonderland (1865) is a novel written by English author Charles Lutwidge Dodgson under the pseudonym Lewis Carroll. It tells the story of a girl named Alice who falls down a rabbit-hole into a fantasy world populated by peculiar and anthropomorphic creatures."
      }
    ]
  }
}

FURTHER EDIT: I've double-checked in MongoDB Compass, and it's showing that the Wishlist array consists of ObjectIDs and not full Objects (unless I misunderstand):
Screenshot from MongoDBCompass

please include the document - which you think should populate, into your original post. The particular profile document and its related book document - both would help to check.

The schema indicates Wishlist should be an array of ObjectId, not an array of documents with an _id field.

@Joe I'm a tad confused (bear with me I'm new to this!)  I mean for the Profile.find({ _id: profileId }) to find the id field for the profile.  Why is it doing the latter?

The Profile.find({ _id: profileId }) should fetch the document from the profiles collection that has _id ==  profileId.  The populate call is expecting the WishList field to hold an array of ObjectId, instead it holds and array of objects.

@Joe I posted a screenshot, and it looks like it does have an array of ObjectIds and not objects.  So I'm still not sure what I'm doing wrong.
